# Are student jobs/internships considered jop hopping?

Tags: interviewing, new-job, job-hopping

I'm currently finishing my master studies and so far I have had 3 different part time jobs/internships each lasting 6 months with a year and months apart from each other. (I could have stayed longer, but I decided not to, since I wanted to experience different companies during my studies.)

After I finish my studies I want to look for a long term job (part or full time), but I am unsure if I will look like a job hopper to the employers?

Would I be considered a job hopper in this situation?

Comment: Just to clarify, was it an internship or a part-time job? You seem to mention it's both, how come? Also, what kind of long term job you plan to seek? Is it related to your current jib/internships?

Comment: I live in Europe and I am not exactly sure how to distinguish. So, I sign the agreement as I am working a part time job and this part time job has the title Intern. Yes, it is all software development and I would look for the same job.

Comment: Thanks, so those offers were for a fixed period of time (6 months) and then you had the chance of staying if offered?

Comment: They were indefinite (not sure if proper legal term), but I chose to leave after 6 months.

Comment: Did these internships overlap with your studies?  Did the timing occur within the undergrad or masters calendar, or did you work for while and then go back to school

Comment: I never stopped my studies, so these were always overlapping. One was during undergrad and two during master studies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How bad does it look to consistently quit a job after a year](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/108149/how-bad-does-it-look-to-consistently-quit-a-job-after-a-year)

Comment: I did this all the way through uni, have multiple part-time jobs/paid and unpaid internships on my CV and no one have ever asked why I had so many, it's clear that I was also studying for that period and just looking for the experience. In fact, my first job was really impressed about my experience in so many fields

Answer (score 11):

Unlikely. When you are a student, the expectation is your studies take priority. Internships exist to teach students about the working world and give the company a bit of a labour boost while you're at it. And hey, after your studies are done and you've proven to be an asset, maybe they might help you skip the job hunting stage and let you come back to work with them as a full-on employee.

Part time work while being a student is also often done under the understanding that this work agreement is good for, at a maximum, until they are no longer a student and need (and have found) full-time work. Some companies may offer full-time work once the studies are done but depending on the situation, this is often not an attractive offer for the student (e.g: Nice STEM degree. Wanna work as a checkout cashier full time?).

Comment: This is a good answer. It's important to realize that "job hopper" can only really apply to someone that *should* have settled down but really hasn't (i.e. someone with 5 or 6 years of professional experience post-education, but they've worked for 7 or 8 companies in that time). No one expects that people "fresh" out of school and new to the workforce will immediately have settled down into their perfect long term job, and much less would anyone ever expect someone to have stable, long term positions before they've even graduated.

Answer (score 4):

This may vary between different cultures but most probably and extremely likely:

**NO,** you are a student in their eyes and supposed to prioritize your studies. Short employments are expected. It would probably look good to have one of those continued employments from internship because that tells to them that you have shown your capabilities during the internship.

Only way it would be considered job hopping would be that you staid one month in an internship but left as you got a higher salary in an another internship. You would need to make that into a pattern occurring at least twice. Then you would need to include those short lived internships in your CV or otherwise there is extremely low changes that they would hear about such behavior.